# How to use a custom configuration file for composer in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to call a custom configuration file per environment when using php's composer and amazon's elastic beanstalk?
for example, when having a "composer.dev.json" & "composer.master.json" files (one of them could request files from a "dev" version/branch and the other one for stable files).

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk has composer built-in. In order to use it, the only thing you need to do is adding a "composer.json" file in your root folder. In case you want to use a custom composer file for each version, it can also be accomplished relatively easily. Create a folder named ".elasticbeanstalk" and its relative file "optionsettings.branch-name" - it should be created using the "eb cli", particularity, with the commands "eb init" and "eb branch"-  more info can be found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cmd-commands.html.

After we have the optionsettings file, we should define a param named "COMPOSER" in there and just have it to point to the custom composer file we would like to run, for example:
`[aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment]
COMPOSER=composer.dev.json`

on your next deploment, it should run the composer using composer.dev.json